# Skylake L2 cache enhanced by reducing associativity?

Tags: x86, cpu, intel, cpu-cache

In [Intel's optimization guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf#page=35), section 2.1.3, they list a number of enhancements to the caches and memory subsystem in Skylake (emphasis mine):

> The cache hierarchy of the Skylake microarchitecture has the following
>   enhancements:
>
> - Higher Cache bandwidth compared to previous generations.
> - Simultaneous handling of more loads and  stores enabled by enlarged buffers.
> - Processor can do two page walks in parallel compared  to one in Haswell microarchitecture and earlier  generations.
> - Page split load penalty down from 100 cycles in previous generation to 5 cycles.
> - L3 write bandwidth increased from 4 cycles pe r line in previous generation to 2 per line.
> - Support for the CLFLUSHOPT instruction to flush ca che lines and manage memory ordering of flushed  data using SFENCE.
> - Reduced performance penalty for a software prefetch that specifies a NULL pointer.
> - **L2 associativity changed from 8 ways to 4 ways.**

The final one caught my eye. In what way is a reduction in the number of ways an enhancement? By itself, it seems that fewer ways is strictly worse than more ways. Of course, I get that there might be valid engineering reasons why a reduction in the number of ways could be a tradeoff that enables other enhancements, but here it is positioned, by itself, as an enhancement.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's strictly worse for performance of the L2 cache.

According to [this AnandTech writeup of SKL-SP (aka skylake-avx512 or SKL-X)](http://www.anandtech.com/show/11550/the-intel-skylakex-review-core-i9-7900x-i7-7820x-and-i7-7800x-tested/4), Intel has stated that "the main reason [for reducing associativity] was to make the design more modular".  Skylake-AVX512 has 1MiB of L2 cache with 16-way associativity.

Presumably the drop to 4-way associativity doesn't hurt *too* badly in the dual and quad-core laptop and desktop parts (SKL-S), since there's lots of bandwidth to L3 cache.  I think if Intel's simulations and testing had found that it hurt a lot, they would have put in the extra design time to keep the 8-way 256k cache on non-AVX512 Skylake.

---

The upside of lower associativity is power budget.  It could indirectly help performance by allowing more turbo headroom,  but mostly they did it to improve efficiency, NOT to improve speed.  **Freeing up some room in the power budget allows them to spend it elsewhere**.  Or not to spend all of it, and just use less power.

Mobile and many-core-server CPUs care a lot about power budget, much more than high-end quad-core desktop CPUs.

**The heading on the list should more accurately read "changes", not "enhancements"**, but I'm sure the marketing department wouldn't let them write anything that didn't sound positive.  :P  At least Intel documents things accurately and in detail, including the ways new CPUs are worse than older designs.

---

[Anandtech's SKL writeup](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9582/intel-skylake-mobile-desktop-launch-architecture-analysis/5) suggests that dropping the associativity freed up the power budget to increase L2 bandwidth, which (in the big picture) compensates for the increased miss rate.

IIRC, Intel has a policy that any proposed design change must have a 2:1 ratio of perf gain to power cost, or something like that.  So presumably if they lost 1% performance but save 3% power with this L2 change, they do it.  The 2:1 number might be correct, if I'm remembering this correctly, but the 1% and 3% example are totally made up.

There was some discussion of this change in one of the podcast interviews David Kanter did right after details were released at IDF.  [IDK if this is the right link](http://techreport.com/review/28999/the-tr-podcast-186-talking-skylake-architecture-with-david-kanter).

Comment: Here's [another interesting theory](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#867): that the Skylake-S (i.e., original Skylake) had several architectural modifications in anticipation of AVX-512 support in the later Skylake-X and Skylake Xeon lines, even though Skylake-S didn't support it. In particular: _[SKL reducing associativity to 4] was preparation to increasing cache size - SKL-S cache is just a quarter of SKL-X cache with the same organization, and reduced associativity allowed to reduce transistor budget of massive 1MB cache._. Just speculation but interesting nonetheless!

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yeah, I had the same thought after reading [AnandTech's SKL-X writeup](http://www.anandtech.com/show/11550/the-intel-skylakex-review-core-i9-7900x-i7-7820x-and-i7-7800x-tested/4), where they make the same claim: reduced L2 associativity was at least partly to make it more modular.  So the assumption that SKL-S gets an overall speedup from spending the power budget elsewhere may not be correct.  (It doesn't rule it out, though.  It may still be an overall good or neutral change for SKL-S.  And Intel wouldn't have done it if they think it's too bad.)