# Why are set cache associativity in modern day processors 8-way set associative?

Tags: caching, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, amd-processor

Is there any particular advantage with 8 way set cache associativity that I fail to see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that [Ice Lake bumps that up to 12-way, 48kiB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809991/how-does-the-indexing-of-the-ice-lakes-48kib-l1-data-cache-work) (adding more ways to each set, same indexing).  There's nothing magic about 8-way specifically.  Previous AMD designs, like K8 and Bulldozer, experimented with different L1d and L1i geometries, like 64k / 2-way.  (Less successfully than Intel's 16k/4-way then 32k/8-way, though.)

**For an L1d / L1i cache, 8-way allows a 32k cache to be VIPT without aliasing** ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279049/minimum-associativity-for-a-pipt-l1-cache-to-also-be-vipt-accessing-a-set-witho)), given x86's 4k pages.  32kiB is a good power-of-2 "sweet spot" that's small enough to be fast, but large enough and associative enough for good hit rates, and 8-way is the minimum associativity if you want to avoid needing extra tricks to avoid aliasing.

See [Why is the size of L1 cache smaller than that of the L2 cache in most of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666728/why-is-the-size-of-l1-cache-smaller-than-that-of-the-l2-cache-in-most-of-the-pro/38549736#38549736) for more about why we have cache hierarchies (because it's impossible to build a huge cache the size of L2 or L3 with the latency and number of read/write ports we need/want for L1, and trying would be a bad way to spend your power budget).  See also [Which cache mapping technique is used in intel core i7 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092541/which-cache-mapping-technique-is-used-in-intel-core-i7-processor)

---

**8-way is also associative "enough", e.g. most loops over arrays have fewer than 8 total input and output streams** (which would alias each other in L1d if they were coming from the same offsets in page-aligned arrays), and it's a known problem to have more.  (And some forms of 4k aliasing of different accesses is also a known problem that software mostly tries to avoid.)

Also note that SKL's 256k L2 cache is only 4-way associative, vs. SKX's 1MiB 16-way L2.  ([Skylake L2 cache enhanced by reducing associativity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957181/skylake-l2-cache-enhanced-by-reducing-associativity)).  And L3 caches are typically more than 8-way associative, but I guess you're talking about L1d / L1i caches.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.